# Web Audio: Karplus Strong String Synthesis

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Edit: Cleaned up the code and the player (on Github) a little so it's easier to set the frequency

I'm [trying to synthesize](https://github.com/achalddave/Audio-API-Frequency-Generator/blob/master/strings.js) strings using the [Karplus Strong string synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karplus%E2%80%93Strong_string_synthesis) algorithm, but I can't get the string to tune properly. Does anyone have any idea?

As linked above, the code is on Github: https://github.com/achalddave/Audio-API-Frequency-Generator (the relevant bits are in `strings.js`).

Wiki has the following diagram:

[image: Karplus Strong String Synthesis diagram]

So essentially, I generate the noise, which then gets output and sent to a delay filter simultaneously. The delay filter is connected to a low-pass filter, which is then mixed with the output. According to Wikipedia, the delay should be of N samples, where N is the sampling frequency divided by the fundamental frequency (`N = f_s/f_0`).

Excerpts from my code:

Generating the noise (`bufferSize` is 2048, but that shouldn't matter too much)

```
var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, bufferSize, context.sampleRate);
var bufferSource = context.createBufferSource();
bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

var bufferData = buffer.getChannelData(0);
for (var i = 0; i < delaySamples+1; i++) {
    bufferData[i] = 2*(Math.random()-0.5); // random noise from -1 to 1
}
```

Create a delay node

```
var delayNode = context.createDelayNode();
```

We need to delay by `f_s/f_0` samples. However, the delay node takes the delay in seconds, so we need to divide that by the samples per second, and we get `(f_s/f_0) / f_s`, which is just `1/f_0`.

```
var delaySeconds = 1/(frequency);
delayNode.delayTime.value = delaySeconds;
```

Create the lowpass filter (the frequency cutoff, as far as I can tell, shouldn't affect the frequency, and is more a matter of whether the string "sounds" natural):

```
var lowpassFilter = context.createBiquadFilter();
lowpassFilter.type = lowpassFilter.LOWPASS; // explicitly set type
lowpassFilter.frequency.value = 20000; // make things sound better
```

Connect the noise to the output and the delay node (`destination = context.destination` and was defined earlier):

```
bufferSource.connect(destination);
bufferSource.connect(delayNode);
```

Connect the delay to the lowpass filter:

```
delayNode.connect(lowpassFilter);
```

Connect the lowpass to the output and back to the delay*:

```
lowpassFilter.connect(destination);
lowpassFilter.connect(delayNode);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I can't figure out whether the issue is my code, my interpretation of the algorithm, my understanding of the API, or (though this is least likely) an issue with the API itself.

---

*Note that on Github, there's actually a Gain Node between the lowpass and the output, but this doesn't really make a big difference in the output.

Comment: I'm just fiddling with this, and I really don't know what I'm doing. But try setting the frequency to 241. On my Mac that creates some weird noise. Maybe that tells you something? You seem a lot more proficient with the maths and theoretics. :)

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. To be honest, apart from one EE course I'm not too familiar with the theory either, so much of this is piecing things together and asking around. Thanks for the help, though, this might give some insight if I poke around more.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue since I think Lowpass is the default, but you should probably set your filter type explicitly in the code... something like `lowpassFilter.type = lowpassFilter.LOWPASS`.

Comment: That would probably make the code more explicit. I'll update that. (it unfortunately doesn't fix the issue..., thanks though)

Comment: Turns out it's not just that I can't get it to play the right frequency, but that playing the same frequency multiple times doesn't play the same notes...

Comment: Whoops, never mind. The strings are consistent, just not the right tune. (I have terrible ears)

Comment: This is really puzzling. At first I thought that maybe Web Audio delay nodes couldn't handle such low delay times, but if that was the case there should be an upper level where the pitch doesn't increase anymore, which doesn't seem to be the case. Another strange thing is that the pitch isn't consistent over the octaves either. Pitches of 220, 440 and 880 doesn't generate the same note in different octaves. This leads me to think that there might be an error in the calculations somewhere, but I can't see where.

Comment: Independently, I implemented the exact same thing you did, with the exact same result (that is, problem). Then I found this. If I figure anything out, I'll update here.

Comment: BTW here's a PDF of a paper by Jaffe & Smith stating the algorithm in another way, that makes it seem (see equation (1)) like neither Wikipedia or we are mistaken about how the algorithm is supposed to work http://www.jaffe.com/Jaffe-Smith-Extensions-CMJ-1983.pdf

Comment: Glad to know I wasn't wrong about the algorithm, considering how long I'd spent looking at the code, heh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I think is the problem. I don't think the `DelayNode` implementation is designed to handle such tight feedback loops. For a 441 Hz tone, for example, that's only 100 samples of delay, and the `DelayNode` implementation probably processes its input in blocks of 128 or more. <s>(The `delayTime` attribute is "k-rate", meaning changes to it are only processed in blocks of 128 samples. That doesn't prove my point, but it hints at it.) So the feedback comes in too late, or only partially, or something.</s>

EDIT/UPDATE: As I state in a comment below, the actual problem is that a DelayNode in a cycle adds 128 sample frames between output and input, so that the observed delay is `128 / sampleRate` seconds longer than specified.

My advice (and what I've begun to do) is to implement the whole Karplus-Strong including your own delay line in a `JavaScriptNode` (now known as a `ScriptProcessorNode`). It's not hard and I'll post my code once I get rid of an annoying bug that can't possibly exist but somehow does.

Incidentally, the tone you (and I) get with a `delayTime` of `1/440` (which is supposed to be an A) seems to be a G, two semitones below where it should be. Doubling the frequency raises it to a B, four semitones higher. (I could be off by an octave or two - kind of hard to tell.) Probably one could figure out what's going on (mathematically) from a couple more data points like this, but I won't bother.

EDIT: Here's my code, certified bug-free.

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

var frequency = 440;
var impulse = 0.001 * context.sampleRate;

var node = context.createJavaScriptNode(4096, 0, 1);
var N = Math.round(context.sampleRate / frequency);
var y = new Float32Array(N);
var n = 0;
node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
  var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < e.outputBuffer.length; ++i) {
    var xn = (--impulse >= 0) ? Math.random()-0.5 : 0;
    output[i] = y[n] = xn + (y[n] + y[(n + 1) % N]) / 2;
    if (++n >= N) n = 0;
  }
}

node.connect(context.destination);
```

Comment: This works? I'll try it tomorrow. If it does, I can not overstate how awesome that is (and how much I appreciate the help). I had considered implementing it as a JavascriptNode, but I'd run into performance issues the last time I tried that with another experiment.

Comment: Also, what was the "bug that can't possibly exist"? And second, is the DelayNode implementation problem bug report worthy? If so, I'd bug you to report it (I would myself, but it seems you understand it better) and post the link here.

Comment: The bug was not keeping a reference in code to the generating audio nodes. Oversimplifying: `context.createJavaScriptNode().connect(context.destination)` didn't retain a reference to the JS node, and it gets garbage collected. I'd consider this a bug, which hopefully I'll remember to file with Chromium.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider the DelayNode behavior a bug. Perhaps its a documentation/specification bug - the spec should probably specify limit to the delay time, or else specify a way for the implementation to express one.

Comment: Incidentally, the Chrome's DelayNode processing block size appears to be 512 samples, so you wouldn't be able to simulate a K-S tone above 86 Hz with it, so we're pretty much below audible range. The spec makes it illegal to connect a feedback loop with a zero delay, but I suppose it should be illegal to connect a feedback loops with a too-short delay instead.

Comment: There's already a bug report for my "impossible" bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82795

Comment: Ha, I'd run into that bug before while playing around, and saw that same report as well a while back. Anyway, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Correction: the Chrome bug is that a DelayNode in a cycle adds 128 sample frames between output and input. I attempted to enter a bug report twice but got Error 400's twice, so I gave up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means we have to deal with the speed issues due to the JSNode. I was messing with my computer's sampling rate recently, and set it to 192kHz. Everything else (i.e. all audio) works, but there's significant stuttering with the string synthesis :( It works perfectly with 44.1kHz, though.

Comment: Asked info on this topic on https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-html5/ukFxlLKwwZo

Comment: @Grumdrig is it possible to get hold of an e-mail address of yours? I saw your karplus-strong implementation on bitbucket and I'd like to ask you some info

Comment: @janesconference Sure. My email shows up in my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/167531/grumdrig (and frankly, it's efredricksen@gmail.com).

Comment: Argh, really, it doesnt show on your profile page (that, or I'm becoming blind). I just mailed you, thx.

Comment: Sorry; you're right. Not at all clear what shows up for others and what doesn't.